# fscanf does not work in a ctype python call

Tags: python, c, ctypes, scanf

I am trying to wrap around google's word2vec for their newsgroup pre-trained vectors in python using ctypes.

I have a chunk of code here:

```
void initialize(){
  ...
  long long words, size;
  char *fname = "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz";
  strcpy(file_name, fname);
  printf("%s\n", file_name);
  f = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if (f == NULL) {
      printf("Input file not found\n");
      return -1;
  }

  fscanf(f, "%lld ", &words);
  fscanf(f, "%lld", &size);
  printf("size of words is %d\n", words);
  ...
}
```

This code runs fine when I call it from a main function. However, when I compile it to a .so file and call it from ctypes, words always gets zero. Checking with ftell, I notice that fscanf does not move the file pointer forward and fscanf always returns 0. Its a binary file so I'm not sure what the fscanf work around here would be apart from converting this 3 GB binary file to a more massive .csv and reading it from there.

How can this be fixed? A alternate route avoiding fscanf in this case would also work.

Comment: I'm not an expert in ctypes but couldn't it be a conflict between what it ``understands" as `long long` and what the C compiler does, in terms of number of bytes? You could check the type table in https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html maybe it can help you.

Comment: @lord I checked the size of long long and it corresponds to 8 bytes on both ctypes and on my machine with sizeof(long long). I don't see whu this would be relevant since the execution is purely on the C side.

Comment: @chux As I menitoned, fscanf returns 0 which indicates an early failure according to the man pages but I am unsure as to why this is happening only during the call from python.

Comment: @ArtisanV Sorry about that. IAC: When `fscanf()` returns 0, use `int ch = fgetc(f);` to read the offending  `char`, then report that.  I suspect the file is written in binary (note the "rb") and code needs to use `fread()` to read the binary and not `fscanf()` which reads the textual representation.

Comment: Is "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz" a compressed file?  If so, then there is a way to uncompresses the file and pipe its output, on the fly, as input to your code.  It has been a while since I've done that.  (it is easy with stdin)

Comment: @chux indeed it is a compressed file. It seems this could be my issue. I will uncompress it and report back.

Comment: @chux, this resolved my issue. Could you make an answer for this so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's file is a compressed file "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz" and code is designed to read the uncompressed version.

Re-try with the uncompressed version.